# Change 'Created Time' in yaml file to 'Current Time'

Tags: python, django, yaml

In my application I have a yaml file, which was created in django by using the command ./manage.sh  dumpdata. In it the created time is hardcoded like this..

```
created_on: 2012-08-22 06:17:03.053740
```

i.e. the time when the yaml file was created by me.

I want it to display the time as the current time or the time when the yaml file was executed at the customer's end.
Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are for the records that are exported by `dumpdata` not when the file was created. The time the file was created will be part of the file's meta information that you can read from the file system.

To get the time the file was created:

```
>>> import os.path, time
>>> time.ctime(os.path.getctime('test.png'))
'Tue Sep  4 09:48:24 2012'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the interestng info. but that isnt what I was looking for. I want a way to change the 'created_on' value in a yaml file, to the current time, or the time the yaml file was executed.

Comment: So you want to import the yaml file, and then modify the records, and then rewrite the yaml file again?

Comment: After I deploy the app to my client, and he runs it, at that time the yam file is executed on his end.. And I want the 'created_on' value to reflect the time when he runs that app and not when I created the yaml file as is presently showing.

Comment: Instead of doing that, set [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) or [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) depending on what you want.